# [Solved]Unity - Unavailable product in iap subscriptions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, subscription

Unavailable product basic1month-5dollar99cents-basic1month-5dollar99cents
Unavailable product basic-12months-64dollars99cents-basic-12months-64dollars99cents

- In google play console Added and Activated both IAP subscriptions.
- Published in Closed Testing - Apha

Still showing Unavailable product Error, What have i done wrong Please guide me

Is it because of product naming??

[Solved] - i was using Subscription Plan ID, we have to use subscription ID not inside plan ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the [Unity's IAP documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPSettingUp.html) it should help you understand every step needed for setting up the IAP.

You also have there the "Troubleshooting" section, which can help you to see what you have done or did not do right.